# Removing redundant SQL queries (in PHP) by using JOIN

Tags: php, sql, join

I am trying to clean up my SQL queries and use JOIN in just ONE where I once used TWO queries.

Here is former code (in PHP):

```
$cat = "books";  // as a test 

$query = "SELECT category, cat_id FROM master_cat WHERE category = '{$cat}'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT item, spam, cat_id FROM items WHERE cat_id = ' " . $cat_id . "' ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM item) ASC;");  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    if ($row['spam'] < 2)
        $output[] = $row;


print(json_encode($output));  // added!
```

I am trying to just remove the top query and use a JOIN.  The updated SQL statement is this:

EDIT:  I made a mistake in original question.  Basically user input gives us $cat = "something".  There is "something" in master_cat table with a cat_id.  That cat_id is also in the items table.  That is where I need the tables to connect -- and the WHERE clause needs to incorporate "$cat"

UPDATED QUERY:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT i.item, i.spam, mc.cat_id AS Category
FROM items as i
INNER JOIN master_cat as mc
ON i.cat_id = mc.cat_id
WHERE i.cat_id = '{$cat}'
ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM i.item) ASC;");
```

then:

```
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    if ($row['spam'] < 2)
        $output[] = $row;
```

I receive this in the browser:
null.

Can someone guide me on how to properly use JOIN which I know will REALLY clean things up here and make more efficient coding.  I just watched a tutorials but still am not quite getting it.

*HERE IS FINAL CODE THAT WORKS*

```
$cat = $_POST['category']; // yes, yes, injection.  this is just the short version.

$result = mysql_query("SELECT i.item, i.cat_id, i.spam,  mc.cat_id, mc.category, TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM i.item) as CleanItem
FROM items as i
INNER JOIN master_cat as mc
ON i.cat_id = mc.cat_id
WHERE mc.category = '{$cat}'
ORDER BY CleanItem ASC;");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    if ($row['spam'] < 2)
        $output[] = $row;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have reference the `items` table by its full name in the `WHERE` clause, you should be using the alias you created (`i`).

You also have an ambiguous column reference `item` in your `ORDER BY` clause.

Try changing the last two lines to:

```
WHERE i.cat_id = '{$cat_id}'
ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM i.item) ASC
```

You should also inspect `mysql_error()` to get a string description of the error, which would have pointed you straight to the problem.

Comment: hey thanks, that was an obvious error I missed.  Still failing the query though.

Comment: @KickingLettuce What does `mysql_error()` say? Also  did you change the `ORDER BY` line as well?

Comment: Oh no I forgot.  But I changed it and its still blank.

Comment: I added this echo "The Error is: " . mysql_error();  and it outputs this 'echo "The Error is: ";' -- so still blank.

Comment: @KickingLettuce Where did you add it? It should be immediately after `mysql_query()`. Also, if it still comes out blank, can you check `mysql_num_rows()`?

Comment: @KickingLettuce Oh wait, hang on - you did remember to pass the string to `mysql_query()` didn't you? In your original code, `$sql` is a mysql result resource, but in your new code it's just a string containing the query...

Comment: I will try to fix that I; I do apologize and see part of this is my fault.  $cat_id is not defined.  but $cat is ("books").  I need to do a where clause where "? = $cat"

Comment: @KickingLettuce I didn't even spot that, yes you should change the where clause to `WHERE i.cat_id = '{$cat}'`

Comment: yeah.. still not fixed. now browser says "null".  I updated and added more code.

Comment: Hang on a second - there is an extra space in the `cat_id = ' " . $cat_id . "` in your original code - is that just a copy/paste error or is it actually there?

Comment: Hey thanks for your help.. there was another column I needed to add mc.category and compare $cat to that.  And it works!  I am editing final code above. If you want to edit your answer I can mark you correct.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: Ugh, yeh. Now you say that it is obvious. I'm too tired for this I think. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT i.item, i.spam, mc.cat_id AS Category
FROM items as i
INNER JOIN master_cat as mc
ON i.cat_id = mc.category
WHERE items.cat_id = '{$cat_id}'
ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM item) ASC";
```

Since you aliased it you have to keep it as aliased: fix the second to last line:

```
WHERE i.cat_id = '{$cat_id}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT i.item, i.spam, mc.cat_id AS Category
FROM items as i
INNER JOIN master_cat as mc ON i.cat_id = mc.cat_id
WHERE i.cat_id = '{$cat_id}'
ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM item) ASC";
```

If you alias `items` as `i`, you should use `i` everywhere else. Besides, mc.category does not seem to exist so I replaced it with `mc.cat_id`. What does mysql_error say?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting false as your response to the initial query and not a result set

You should join on i.cat_id = mc.cat_id

You should also probably perform your i.item cleaning (i.e. removing 'The ') in the select statement (even as a seperate field if you need to keep i.item intact) and then order by that field.

You should reference i.cat_id = '{$cat_id]}', not items.cat_id

Comment: thank you. I did trythis (which was an error on my part), but problem still not fixed...

Comment: Also, great tip on the Select "cleaning".  I added that to my final code.  +1 for that.